# 403 Forbidden error only on www.domain.com/file/ but not file.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a file in the root folder www.domain.com/file/ that gives me 403 forbidden error "You don't have permission to access /file/ on this server."

If i change the url to www.domain.com/file.php it works fine, permissions are set to 664 and i made a copy of the file with a different name, uploaded it to the same folder and it works perfectly fine.

This started to happen while changing the .htaccess file so i'll leave it in case it's relevant.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Other pages are working fine under the same directory (www.domain.com/page for example) and i've also noticed that if i try to go to www.domain.com/file it redirects to www.domain.com/file/

Comment: you must use *allow indexing* option.